# Program skipping some lines when trying to read

Tags: c, fgets

I'm trying to read this kinda of file

```
0 //Lonely number that represents the turn of a game
0 0 3 1 2 2
0 1 0 0 3 0
0 2 9 2 0 1
0 3 11 2 3 1

1
4 6 7 8 5 6
3 5 6 7 7 8
1 4 5 6 9 6
4 5 7 6 5 4
```

but in my code, everytime i try to detect a new line, the program just take a complety random line and write

```
while( fgets(line,255,*save) != NULL){
        
        printf("The line says: %s",line);
        
        if(line[0] =='\n'){
         //the pointer is because the file was passed to a function 
            fscanf(*save, "%*[^\n]\n"); //To skip this new line and get the one integer
            fscanf(*save,"%d",&turno);  //get the lonely number
            printf("Turno: %d\n",turno); 
            getch();
        }
    
            fscanf(*save,"%d %d %d %d %d %d",&player,&pilha,&id,&x,&y,&qtd); //Get the integers from each line
            printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n",player,pilha,id,x,y,qtd);
    
    }
```

Comment: Instead of trying to kludge the newlines, read every line with `fgets`. Then extract 4 integers with a single `sscanf` and use its return value (the number of successful items scanned) to determine whether there was 0, 1, or 4 integers on that line.

Comment: When `if(line[0] =='\n')` is true, then the empty line has already been read by `fgets`. When you do `fscanf(*save, "%*[^\n]\n")` you skip the *next* line. the one with the single number.

Comment: The input file does not seem to match the code. The file contains lines with 0, 1 or 4 numbers while the code tries to read 1 or 6 numbers. Please [edit] your question and create a [mre], i.e. a program we can compile and run to reproduce the problem, the example input, the corresponding actual output and the expected output.

Comment: `fscanf` doesn't do lines.  You will not be able to read this file with `fscanf` alone.

Comment: You *can* read this file with `fscanf` alone, but you will not be able to distinguish between this file and a similar file that replaces all the newlines with other whitespace.  If such an input is to be considered invalid, you will not be able to detect that with the `scanf` family.

Comment: @WilliamPursell To read this file with `fscanf` alone I think you'd have to assume it's always exactly four lines of six between the single lines of one.